# .htaccess redirect all to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have this site, say `http://example.com/`. I want all requests to redirect (the user has to see the url in his address bar) to `http://example.com/#!/the_requested_page`.

So this is what I want to happen:

- Request `http://example.com/`  **=>**  Show `http://example.com/`
- Request `http://example.com/somepage`  **=>**  Show `http://example.com/#!/somepage`
- Request `http://example.com/#!/somepage` **=>**  Show `http://example.com/#!/somepage`

How can this be done with the .htaccess file?

I tried this, but it doesn't do the second part of the list above.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/#!/

# Don't apply to URLs that go to existing files or folders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all those to insert /folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#!/$1 [L]
```

If I request `http://example.com/somepage` it shows that in the address bar, but the website shows the home page (`http://example.com`).

Besides that, this doesn't redirect, but it just rewrites...

I hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the first condition. The `#` part of the URL is *never sent to the server* so there's no way for you to match against it. Then change the rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /#!/$1 [L,R,NE]
```